# Print only the annotations of a pdf

Tags: pdf, printing, annotations

I have a pdf that has been annotated, and would like to print (or extract) just the annotations (it's a long pdf that's relatively sparsely annotated). Is this possible?

Comment: See also this super user question: [How to export comments from a PDF file?](https://superuser.com/q/698811/419414) and this stackoverflow question [parse annotations from a pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106098/parse-annotations-from-a-pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try putting all annotations in one layer (Layer A) and the rest on the content in another layer (Layer B). Then you can set Layer A as visible while printing and Layer B as not visible.

Comment: Annotations aren't part of the page's content, they float above.  None the less, your suggestion would work.  Put ALL the page content in a layer and hide it.

Comment: @Mark Storer Yes, your are right, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to put annotations on a separate layer?

Answer (score 2):

You can extract your annotations into a text or a .doc file by using this simple [online tool](http://www.sumnotes.net).

This tool extracts highlights and notes from your PDF-files. After you got your annotations exported into a text or a .doc file, print it using standard document printing feature available in your operating system.

Comment: Hello and welcome to superuser.com. Please do not advertise for your own products here. Answer the question with a solution and move on. I have asked the moderators to approve removing the part of your answer which is redundant and leave that which is usefull.