# How to use poppler utils to extract annotations from PDF files?

Tags: bash, pdf, comments

I would like to use the command line tools from poppler-utils to extract annotations from pdf files.

I have found some information under a similar question [how to export comments from a pdf file](https://superuser.com/questions/698811/how-to-export-comments-from-a-pdf-file)  and a stack over flow question [Parse annotations from a pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106098/parse-annotations-from-a-pdf)  (oriented towards a python based solution, not working at this stage).

A search returns the [annotation utils class reference](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/api/qt5/classPoppler_1_1AnnotationUtils.html) I have tried to find out a command line argument in the various [poppler command line utilities](https://www.mankier.com/package/poppler-utils) but I couldn't find one.