# Is there a automatic way to extract highlighted text from pdf?

Tags: command-line, pdf

Is there a command-line solution to extract highlighted text from pdf?

I have a bunch of pdf documents where I personally annotated, and was wondering if there is a convenient way to automatically extract this to the text file

EDIT
This is not a duplicate question in that I am looking for a *command-line* solution like ImageMagick for image processing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Print only the annotations of a pdf](http://superuser.com/questions/275964/print-only-the-annotations-of-a-pdf)

Comment: Related: [How do I extract highlighted text only from PDF files in Adobe Acrobat Pro version 9?](http://superuser.com/questions/620880/how-do-i-extract-highlighted-text-only-from-pdf-files-in-adobe-acrobat-pro-versi?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend usage of the nifty little Python library [pdfannots](https://github.com/0xabu/pdfannots), which has the very capability you are looking for.

```
$ pdfannots document.pdf
```

If combined with some other Bash commands, it can produce nicely formatted output. For example:

```
$ pdfannots document.pdf --no-condense | \
# Removing duplicate lines:
cat -n | sort -uk2 | sort -nk1 | cut -f2- | \
# Improving output formatting:
awk '{$1=$1};1' | sed 's/^\(> \)//g' | sed 's/* Page #/\n&/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux you can use `pdfgrep`

Comment: How is it possible to extract highlighted text with `pdfgrep`?

Comment: I was thinking there will be some sort of tag around highlighted text which can be parse with pdfgrep...

Comment: nope -- default highlighting is coordinate positions only